# PHP/Javascript - Posting parameters to page, then parsing new html?

Tags: php, javascript, html, post, parameters

FINAL EDIT:

I got the DOMxpath query to work using the following code:

```
$divs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//div/table[@id='resulttable']");
```

I don't understand, though, why this code doesn't work the same way:

```
$divs = $xpath->query("//table[@id='resulttable']");
```

**ANY IDEAS?**

Comment: You will need a browser to run the Javascript. PHP can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding another answer since this is a totally different question now.

I don't know why it's not working, everything is ok according to manual. But may I suggest using [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) instead? I tried that when I had a similar task. This way you can rewrite you expression as

```
/** @var $pq phpQuery */
$divs = $pq->find('table#resulttable');
```

and use other familiar jQuery methods.

Answer (score 2):

ok. The classes aren't actually listed and searched dynamically via Javascript, it's a pretty standard static form... you're going to want to use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to get the generated pages by submitting your required POST parameters. your POST parameters are:

```
0       TERM    select                  
1       DIVS    select                  
2       CAMPUS  select                  
3       SUBJ    select          4       
4       ATTR    select                  
5       CREDIT  select                  
6           submit  Search
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. Please check above for one more question.

Answer (score 1):

You can POST and fetch results using curl in PHP. Try this tutorial http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-form-post/

Also, you can figure out what parameters to post by inspecting AJAX request in Firebug

Comment: Can you explain how to inspect the AJAX request? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @FatherStorm is right, it's a standard POST request. But you can still view it in Firebug, under the NET tab. Here are the parameters used for POST request on that page: TERM=201100&DIVS=A&CAMPUS=M&SUBJ=ACCT&ATTR=0ANY&CREDIT=A

Comment: Thanks this worked. Please check above for one more question.